# Ubuntu does not boot after upgrade to 14.10

Tags: upgrade

I am using a media device that has Ubuntu installed, and tried upgrading to 14.10.  After the upgrade, device asked me to reboot, which I did.  Now, it will now load.  It tries to boot, and takes me to a general Ubuntu logo page (the one with the five dots).  When I hit ESC, the 'Starting MySQL Server' line has failed.  How can I get around this to either roll back to the factory version of Ubuntu or fix this install?  Holding the SHIFT key on boot does not allow me to enter the boot menu that some have suggested.  Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: "the 'Starting MySQL Server' line has failed. " this probably has nothing to do with it (generally Ubuntu keeps booting if MySQL errors out). The problem will be something before it. Possible method of attacking this: check the log files in /var/log by booting a Live DVD.

Comment: To "roll back" just [restore your last system backup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc).  You're definitely user type 4 if you're running 14.10!!!  To fix the install, boot the liveCD and provide the output to:  `tail -n 20 /var/log/{kern.log,dmesg,syslog}`